# Require admin privileges conditionally

Tags: c#, permissions, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to elevate privileges only when required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required)
>   [Admin rights for a single method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021831/admin-rights-for-a-single-method)

There are a lot of places on the internet that show you how to execute your program with admin privileges. I don't want the user to execute my program with admin privileges all the time. Is it possible to request admin privileges once the application is running?

If I include:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in my application manifest file the program will always prompt a message in order to get admin privileges. I t will be nice if I could decide when to get the admin privileges.

Comment: Looked at that question and it pretty much answers everything you are asking for.