# How to elevate the current C# program only when needed?

Tags: c#, windows, uac, elevation, process-elevation

How would I go about elevating my running C# program only when necessary?

I come from Java and I see programs like IntelliJ only calling on their `"elevator.exe"` when a task requires administrator privileges.

So, I am wondering how I would go about doing the same thing in C#, only elevating the current program when a task needs elevating (for example, an update), and then being able to run the specified task. It wouldn't bother me if I too had to make my own `"elevator.exe"`, I would just like to know how it is done so that I may recreate it.

I'm not trying to just run another program with administrator privileges, I want to give admin access to the *current* program, to perform operations like updates, like IntelliJ does.

Comment: Welcome to c# and stackoverflow, is the answer you seek in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32938785/8306962

Comment: Doesn't the link above lead to a comment about F#, instead of C#?

And no, that is not what I mean.

I do not want it to automatically start with admin privileges, I only want the app to request admin privileges when necessary (like if the app must make a folder in sys32)

Comment: sorry, I hotlinked to the wrong answer, the accepted answer in that thread should perhaps be of some help.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I will have another look.

Comment: Perhaps this thread has what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021878/8306962

Comment: I get System.Security.SecurityException: 'Request for principal permission failed.'

Comment: EDIT: Wait. I think i might understand now. Thanks for the info. (I'll still leave this question open because I don't think i fully understand)

Comment: But how would you restart the host program (as in, relaunch application) from the "updater.exe"?