# Error Access denied to programmatically created folder

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I Have Created document set in that document i have programmatically created an Tempfolder but when i  access that folder it shows error like"Access to the path 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\MyTempFolder' Access is denied"

please guide me.

Comment: Can you post the code here? It may help you to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behavior because you need administrator's rights to access that folder.
The simples solution is to run you program as Administration but I would rather change the folder, otherwise you need to elevate the rights of you app.
Furhter you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically).