# Starting windows service programatically using impersonation

Tags: c#, windows-services, impersonation

I've been searching for an answer for my problem for hours but after trying lots of suggestion I'm still stuck.

I have a C# Windows form based application I work on and I have to launch a windows service (also part of the solution) programatically (when the user clicks the appropriate button). This part is already in place - I can launch the service but... I have some problems in Windows 7 and 2008 Server.

The problem is that I can't do it as my application is loaded by the machine administrator but as a filtered standard and not as full administrator ([more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx#wvduac_topic3)). If we launch the application as Administrator it works fine, but I don't want to bother the user to do it every time.

I would like to know if it is possible to pop the  Windows confirmation screen when the user enters the form where he can start the service - as a full administrator.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IIRC - you can't elevate an existing processes privileges, you would need to spawn a new process to perform the operation which requires it.

[Found a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required) which further explains this.

Comment: Using the "runas" option might mean exception handling is quite difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can either launch another application thorugh ShellExecute (using the runas verb) so Windows would prompt the user or use the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (both when the user clicks on the button).

If you are targeting Windows Server 2008 R2/Windows 7 maybe you can use [Service Trigger Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Best