# How can I ask the user for elevated permissions at runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Some applications, started with a regular user will ask for elevated permissions when necessary (e.g. a file manager needs to write such folder), and then carry on with the operation.

How can I replicate this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tamás pointed out you need to launch a new process with elevated rights. I searched a lot in the past but I did not find any way to elevate the rights of the current process.

Lets say your primary app is App1.exe and then you call a secondary process App2.exe which requires elevated rights.

---

**A. You can embed a manifest in your App2.exe but the simpler way is to create a manifest file [a text file] named App2.exe.manifest with the following contents and put it in the same directory as App2.exe.**
Note: !! Strangely enough, if the name of your application is not App2.exe but App2_install.exe or App2_setup.exe (i.e. if the application name contains the "install" or "setup") an UAC Dialog will appear automatically in Windows Vista / Windows 7 and will ask for elevated rights even there is no manifest file !!
This is a sample of the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<security>
<requestedPrivileges>
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

---

**B. You can use a code like the following in App1.exe to launch the App2.exe**

```
QString AppToExec = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/App2.exe";
// Put any required parameters of App2.exe to AppParams string
QString AppParams = "";
if (0 != genWin32ShellExecute(AppToExec, 
                              "",    // default verb: "open" or "exec"
                              AppParams,
                              false, // run hidden
                              true)) // wait to finish
{
    // (...) handle error
}
```

...and finally, this is the code of the Win32 function genWin32ShellExecute() I created to launch a process or open a document when using QT on a Win32 O/S:

**Header:**

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN  // Implement genWin32ShellExecute() especially for UAC
    #include "qt_windows.h"
    #include "qwindowdefs_win.h"
    #include <shellapi.h>

int genWin32ShellExecute(QString AppFullPath,
                         QString Verb,
                         QString Params,
                         bool ShowAppWindow,
                         bool WaitToFinish);
#endif
```

**CPP:**

```
// Execute/Open the specified Application/Document with the given command
// line Parameters
// (if WaitToFinish == true, wait for the spawn process to finish)
//
// Verb parameter values:
// ""           The degault verb for the associated AppFullPath
// "edit"       Launches an editor and opens the document for editing.
// "find"       Initiates a search starting from the specified directory.
// "open"       Launches an application. If this file is not an executable file, its associated application is launched.
// "print"      Prints the document file.
// "properties" Displays the object's properties.
//
// Ret: 0 = success
//     <0 = error
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
int genWin32ShellExecute(QString AppFullPath,
                         QString Verb,
                         QString Params,
                         bool ShowAppWindow,
                         bool WaitToFinish)
{
    int Result = 0;

    // Setup the required structure
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
    memset(&ShExecInfo, 0, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO));
    ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
    ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
    if (Verb.length() > 0)
        ShExecInfo.lpVerb = reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR *>(Verb.utf16());
    ShExecInfo.lpFile = NULL;
    if (AppFullPath.length() > 0)
        ShExecInfo.lpFile = reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR *>(AppFullPath.utf16());
    ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
    if (Params.length() > 0)
        ShExecInfo.lpParameters = reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR *>(Params.utf16());
    ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
    ShExecInfo.nShow = (ShowAppWindow ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
    ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

    // Spawn the process
    if (ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo) == FALSE)
    {
        Result = -1; // Failed to execute process
    } else if (WaitToFinish)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(ShExecInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    }

    return Result;
}
#endif
```

Comment: It was actually me who pointed it out after my research :P. Thanks for the detailed answer. If the executable name also contains the string "update" it will trigger UAC as well.

Comment: I edited my answer and put your name in the credits :-) I must thank you for asking and give me the motive to publish this code snippet. I remember that I have spend at least 1-2 days when I needed this code because there was no corresponding question in SO.

Comment: Thanks that was not necessary :). I really appreciate that you took the time write this detailed answer, even though the question already had an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

See [this question on elevating privileges only when required in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573086/how-to-elevate-privileges-only-when-required) and [this article on User Account Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx)

To sum it up: one needs to launch a new process with elevated permissions. The elevation level cannot be changed at runtime. Launching with elevated permissions is done either via WinAPI or embedding a correct manifest in the executable.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell: Create two executable files for windows. The regular executable, and a worker exe file that you use to perform "elevated" operations (by passing command line options).

To the second EXE file you add an application manifest file with a [`<requestExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) node.

When launching the worker app, make sure to use the QT function that wraps ShellExecute, NOT CreateProcess as CreateProcess simply fails to launch requireAdministrator apps, whereas ShellExecute (Being a shell function) can perform the UAC elevation prompt.

It is also possible to do this with ActiveX controls, but as you are targeting Qt that seems less appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also launch a COM object in an elevated mode. See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more information.