# Qt (on Windows) setting privilege-level to "requireAdministrator"

Tags: windows, qt

I am using Qt Creator and struggling to make the `.exe` file to run as administrator by default.

Reading through all the solutions online I tried to put this line in my `.pro` file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /MANIFESTUAC:"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'"
```

But still when I check my `.exe` (using notepad) it contains:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
```

Can someone tell me, How to add `requireAdministrator`?

**Temporary Solution:**
Till now I could not find a solution so I made a temporary hack. I made an `.exe` called 
'LaunchAnother.exe' Which will launch my 'main.exe' using following code:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExInfo = {0};
shExInfo.cbSize = sizeof(shExInfo);
shExInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shExInfo.hwnd = 0;
shExInfo.lpVerb = _T("runas");                // Operation to perform
shExInfo.lpFile = _T("main.exe");       // Application to start    
shExInfo.lpParameters = "";                  // Additional parameters
shExInfo.lpDirectory = 0;
shExInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
shExInfo.hInstApp = 0;  

if (ShellExecuteEx(&shExInfo))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(shExInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(shExInfo.hProcess);
}
```

Still waiting for a better solution.

Comment: Is your QtCreator using VC toolchain? You're using VC specific switches, so if your configuration uses g++ then it won't work at all. I also found that you may need to add `CONFIG += embed_manifest_exe`

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the manifest file after compilation using mt.exe.

[Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)

[How to: Embed a Manifest Inside a C/C++ Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[An example manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6137516/999943)

Another option is to create a .res file and point that to your manifest file as shown here:

[How to embed a manifest into a dll with mingw tools only](http://cournape.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/how-to-embed-a-manifest-into-a-dll-with-mingw-tools-only/)

Hope that helps.