# Make Program ask for admin rights with code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I want to make my program ask for admin rights when it starts.
I already found out that you can do this by doing this :

```
Properties -> Linker -> Manifest File -> UAC Execution Level -> requireAdministrator (/level='requireAdministrator')
```

So here is my actual question:

Couldn't I change this setting with my code? Because I can do this for example:

```
#pragma comment (lib, winmm.lib);
```

and adding a lib is a linker setting too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.uacexecutionlevel.aspx

I found this but it doesn't seem to work for me, or is there something I may forget by using this code, beacause the compiler tells me that `property` is undefined?

Comment: Your link is for .NET. It won't work in plain C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I ask the user for elevated permissions at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108851/how-can-i-ask-the-user-for-elevated-permissions-at-runtime)

Comment: but i don't want to write my own manifest file!

Comment: As stated in the accepted answer on the other question, launching a process called `*_setup.exe` or `*_install.exe` through the shell triggers UAC.

Comment: Why don't you do it the way that works?

Comment: you mean with the properties?

Comment: @bcrist, I think it's more like `*(setup|install)*.exe`

Comment: @chris yes, I know, technically I think it's `*(setup|install|update)*.exe`

Comment: @bcrist, Just saw that appended comment :p

Comment: @chris it also appears the program needs to be linked using `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`.  With `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` UAC is not triggered automatically, but `*(setup|install)*.exe` triggers a "Did this program install correctly" on exit if a non-zero status code is returned.  `*(update).exe` does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @bcrist, Interesting, although my test of "setup.exe" that was linked with a console subsystem still brought up the dialog. Considering all it did was print something, it did bring up the troubleshooting dialog after, though.

Comment: @chris Hmm.  The console program I used was an OpenGL program using the console for debugging.  I assumed it was the `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` that suppressed it but maybe there's something else going on.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95677c5a-b331-4b1d-96e7-14fdbea4d65f/how-to-use-vs2010-pragma-manifestuac-on-console-without-ide?forum=vcgeneral

you can add manifest using mt.exe after compiling

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that from code.  The [#pragma comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) directive can pass some information to the linker but it only supports a limited subset of linker commands:

> Only the following (comment-type) linker options are available to be
>   passed to the linker identifier:
>
> [/DEFAULTLIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/229a6ysd.aspx)
>
> [/EXPORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5.aspx)
>
> [/INCLUDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s3hwbhs.aspx)
>
> [/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0y5khy.aspx)
>
> [/MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxz26dz2.aspx)
>
> [/SECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf9b18xk.aspx)

Comment: okay, so I will do it with the project properties. Thanks for your help!