# Copy file with elevated privileges; prompt is fine

Tags: vb.net, elevated-privileges

I need to copy a file into a folder using elevated privileges. A user prompt is fine.

```
IO.File.Copy(vSrcPath, vDestPath)
```

I'm getting

> UnauthorizedAccessExption: Access to the path ... is denied.

How can I copy using admin privileges?

I tried finding the answer but most questions focus on avoiding the prompt. That isn't a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10743396/1070452

Comment: Great! thanks. I guess that makes this a duplicate. Should I just delete this question?

Comment: Close it as a dupe of that - the more things pointing to a good answer, the better.  EDIT: sorry, forgot I could do that myself