# C# WMI user permissions to execute a method

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to find a way to verify if a user has execute methods permissions in order to let know the PC configuration is right to execute any process through WMI.

I've been looking at classes such as Win32_process or Win32_Useraccounts to get that information but I haven't had any luck.

Could anybody kindly advise on this question?

Regards,
Misael.

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36065876/edit) your question at any time. As per question, maybe you don't need to check each individual permission, rather [elevate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/573086/1997232) to admin?

Comment: I don't know if there is a better method, but I usually do the WMI call, and then, I check if there is any error on the buffer (vb script allowed this). If there is an error on the call, so you don't have permission.

Comment: Yeah there are two approaches I think, one of them is making a WMI call and verify acknowledgement code to see if there is any error, the other approach is just verify user is in administrators group.

Before trying any of those approaches, I would like to invest some more time to see if it's possible to get permissions through a class.

Thanks!