# How do I request admin privileges?

Tags: c#, winforms, admin, uac

I need the program I'm making to request admin privileges. If the user denies the pop up message the program will continue but some features will be missing.

I have tried putting the code below in the app.manifest file but when the user denies the program privileges the program does not start.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2271656/57508

Comment: The old question is not the same!

Comment: @i486 I am aware of this, as I did not mark the question as a duplicate. My referenced question is just about "all or nothing" part and the fact that the application determines its elevation-need itself.

Comment: Ok, but this question is now closed and cannot post answers. You had to post only a comment.

Comment: @i486 As I did. It was PatrickHofman who closed this question, but I have nominated the question for reopening! Anyway, there's another method: You could attribute the methods with `[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, Assertion = true)]` and use a `try`/`catch` around the calls.

Comment: @i486: Okay. Misunderstood the question I guess. Next time, please ping me, then I will notice it quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app must restart itself with ProcessStartInfo Verb = "RunAs". Then close current instance (non-admin).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this. By the time your program is running, it's too late - you either have admin privileges or you don't. If you don't, the only way to get those admin privileges is to restart the application as admin.