# Elevating process rigth with UAC without ShellExecute

Tags: c#, uac

We ran into problems with code that already worked to elevate the rights of a helper process that installs a new printer.

I found this answer here, which nearly matches our code:
[Windows 7 and Vista UAC - Programmatically requesting elevation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282448/windows-7-and-vista-uac-programatically-requesting-elevation-in-c-sharp)

The only difference is that we had set ShellExecute to false. This caused a Win32Exception that the process requires elevated rights. Use ShellExecute solved this.

My question is: why? Most likely there is an answer to that that makes sense and would really to understand what happens so I will know next time something similar is required.

Many thanks in advance for all hints!

Comment: The basic "why" is that there's a significant problem with that "helper process".  It should ask for elevation itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to elevate a new process programmatically is to ask the shell to execute the executable file using the verb `runas`. That's the only supported way to do it. In order to pass the `runas` verb to the shell, you need to call a suitable Win32 API function. Possible candidates include `ShellExecute` and `ShellExecuteEx`.

The `UseShellExecute` property determines which API call is used when you call `Process.Start`. If `UseShellExecute` is `true`, then `ShellExecuteEx` is called. Otherwise `CreateProcess` is called.

So, when you set `UseShellExecute` to `false`, you switched to using `CreateProcess`. And `CreateProcess` does not have any mechanism to elevate the new process. So when `UseShellExecute` is `false`, the `runas` verb that you provided is simply ignored because `CreateProcess` does not receive shell verbs.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is because `Process.Start` uses one of two APIs internally: [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) or [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx).  Only the latter supports UAC elevation, which us why you must set `UseShellExecute = true`.

As an interesting aside, there is another way to achieve **UAC elevation without directly starting a new process**.  You can write an out-of-process COM component to perform the actual work that needs to run elevated.  Then, when you instantiate the component, it runs in an elevated process (after the UAC prompt is displayed).  Of course, it's not easy to write out-of-process COM components in .NET without using C++/CLI.  But see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127042/how-to-uac-elevate-a-com-component-with-net) for more information.

Comment: You second paragraph is wrong in that it only applies to special DLLs: "it must be digitally signed by the Windows publisher, which is the certificate used to sign all code included with Windows (it's not sufficient to be signed by Microsoft, so Microsoft software that's not shipped in Windows isn't included)" - so this is pretty exclusive.

Comment: @coderforlife - Thanks for spotting the mistake! The technique does work, but I hastily linked an article that describes something else altogether. I've put a link to another SO post instead. Hopefully this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad that it does indeed work and will now look into using it (I read the article initially because I did want it to work). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Channel 9 video that explains the guts of UAC.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/UAC-What-How-Why)

Architecturally, only ShellExecute has the knowledge of how to launch `Consent.exe` (the UAC dialog). So that's why you must use it.